# Fill NaN using values from different rows which has same column 1 value

Tags: pandas, merge, grouping, fillna

I have this df

```py
dfo = pd.DataFrame([['aa', 'aa1', 1,np.NaN ,np.NaN ,np.NaN ,np.NaN ],
                    ['aa','aa1',np.NaN, np.NaN, 3,np.NaN , np.NaN],
                    ['aa','aa1',np.NaN,np.NaN ,np.NaN , 4,np.NaN ],
                    ['bb','bb1',np.NaN,7 ,np.NaN , np.NaN,np.NaN ],
                    ['bb','bb1',5,np.NaN ,np.NaN , np.NaN,np.NaN ],
                   ],
                   columns=['category','category1','A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E'])
```

[original dataframe - something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKIHq.png)

and I would like to merge the rows by category so that corresponding NaNs are filled from other rows with the same category.

I need this:

```py
dfr = pd.DataFrame([['aa','aa1',1,np.NaN ,3 ,4 ,np.NaN ],

                    ['bb','bb1',5,7 ,np.NaN , np.NaN,np.NaN ],
                   ],
                   columns=['category','category1','A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E'])
```

[required dataframe - something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC5d8.png)

I tried using fillna() however i don't see any option to fill by category row.

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: `dfo.groupby(['category', 'category1'], as_index=False).first()`